# Sonata Media Bundle: Customize Upload Folders

Tags: symfony, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

In my project I have two modules: Curriculum and Documents, both linked to a Company...and these have both file uploads that I managed to get working with Sonata Media and Sonata Classification

Well, I want that files uploaded from my Curriculum Admin Form to be saved in a folder similar like this:
`%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/:nameOfCompany/curriculums/`
and my Documents files that comes from my Documents Admin Form to be saved in:
`%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/:nameOfCompany/documents/`

Please, can you help me accomplish this? There's absolutely NO documentation on how configure Sonata Classification Bundle or Sonata Media Bundle to get this...

Comment: Okay, through search I've found this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057300/how-to-get-sonata-media-bundle-to-generate-pictures-in-separate-folders. The problem is that I need to manage my folder "nameOfCompany" dinamically...and I'm not sure how to do it from a custom Provider

Comment: AFAIK you need to create a custom PathGenerator, look at  the function `generatePath` of `vendor/sonata-project/media-bundle/Generator/DefaultGenerator.php` . This is the function you want to override.